Gutenberg Block variation - how to change the label and instructions
I've registered a block variation of the core/file, and in the JS code I can change the title/description/icon etc. But I can't see how to change the default text ('Upload a file or pick one from your media library.'), once it's on the post.
The default icon/title/instructions text:

These are the classes, so I though that might their names:
components-placeholder__label
components-placeholder__instructions
Here's the JS code, (with lots of testing):
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation( 'core/file', {     
        name: 'wav-file',
        title: 'Wav',
        icon: "format-audio",
        description: 'Use this block to upload wavs',
        keywords: [ "media", "wav", "download" ],
        category: "media",
        isDefault: false,
        label: 'lakjdjdjf',
        placeholder: 'Headingfffffff',
        placeholder__instructions: 'aaaaa',
        instructions: 'instrrrghghg',
        attributes: { 
            className: 'wav-file',
            placeholder: 'Headingfffffff',
            placeholder__instructions: 'aaaaa',
            instructions: 'instrrrghghg',
            style: {
                border: {
                    width: "1px"
                },
                spacing: {
                    padding: {
                        top: "var:preset|spacing|x-small",
                        right: "var:preset|spacing|x-small",
                        bottom:"var:preset|spacing|x-small", 
                        left: "var:preset|spacing|x-small"
                    }
                }
            },
            borderColor: "contrast"
        },
        innerBlocks: [
            [
                'core/file',
                {
                    label: 'lakjdjdjf',
                    placeholder: 'Headingfffffff'
                } 
            ]
        ]
    } );

